# How to disaggregate an accumulated netcdf variable in time using ncl, cdo or nco?

Tags: cdo-climate, nco, ncl

I have a 3D netcdf variable PP = (time, lat, lon) of accumulated precipitation for an entire year and I want to calculate daily values.

I want to do something link in the example, but couldn't find any examples.

I've tried to do a loop in which the subtraction should be between the values with [index+1] minus value [index] (like below)

```
t = f->time(:)   ;size = 365

pp = f->TOTALRAIN(:,:,:) ; time, lat, lon dimensions


do i = 0,dimsizes(t)-1

DailyPp = pp(i,:,:) - pp(i-1,:,:)

end do
```

but that way produces an error.

I need the daily values and only have accumulated precipitation as input information, and thought that a loop like that should be the best way.

How can I do the calculation from the variable???

I'm working with `ncl` but if you have `cdo` or `nco` propositions they're welcome.

Comment: always better to specify the error if you want a ncl solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with two `nco` shell commands

the `ncks` command shifts the records up by one

**ncks -v TOTALRAIN  --msa_usr_rdr -d time,1,364 -d time,364 in.nc shift.nc**

now use `ncbo` to find the difference

**ncbo -v TOTALRAIN  shift.nc in.nc diff.nc**

now the netcdf file diff should contain your daily pp
The final record of TOTALRAIN in this file will be zero's.

Answer (score 1):

In `cdo` you can disaggregate accumulated variables using

```
cdo deltat in.nc diff.nc
```

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244064/converting-an-accumulated-variable-to-timestep-values-in-a-netcdf-file-with-cdo), please refer to the answers there for more details, including inserting the initial timestep.